# Unable to retrieve values from Class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

OK, so we're learning about classes and constructors in school right now. I feel like this should work because it's almost like using struct, but it's kind of irking me because there are no errors in my code. I am unable to retrieve the private values from another class, after using public several methods to obtain their private values.

Output:

```
Input the maximum # of cards for the Baseball card Box: 4                                                                                                                        
Max count of cards: 7                                                                                                                                                            
Current count is: 0                                                                                                                                                              
Spaces left: 7                                                                                                                                                                   

Max count of cards: 7                                                                                                                                                            
Current count is: 1                                                                                                                                                              
Spaces left: 6                                                                                                                                                                   

Max count of cards: 7                                                                                                                                                            
Current count is: 2                                                                                                                                                              
Spaces left: 5                                                                                                                                                                   

Max count of cards: 7                                                                                                                                                            
Current count is: 3                                                                                                                                                              
Spaces left: 4                                                                                                                                                                   

Max count of cards: 7                                                                                                                                                            
Current count is: 4                                                                                                                                                              
Spaces left: 3                                                                                                                                                                   

Max count of cards: 7                                                                                                                                                            
Current count is: 5                                                                                                                                                              
Spaces left: 2                                                                                                                                                                   

Max count of cards: 7                                                                                                                                                            
Current count is: 6                                                                                                                                                              
Spaces left: 1
```

Comment: You never initialize `currentCardCount`, so you have UB when you access it (as you are doing in a bunch of places).

Comment: _"I am unable to retrieve the private values from another class, after using public several methods to obtain their private values."_ What? It looks to me like that's exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Both are initialized between classes, but if the user specifies the max count instead of the default 7, it doesn't loop through say, users max count of 4. SO even if the user inputs a max of 4, then the for loop defaults to 7, and shows 7 output results/

Comment: Calling the constructor for BaseballCardBox 3 times does not set values in earlier objects?  box was not constructed with the input value, and there is no setter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I thought the constructor is used to initialize the class types when its called from main. Should I put get/setters within the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use define the variable `maxCardCount` as `static int` if you want to change its values for all instances of the class. In other words, if you change the value of the variable, it'll be changed for all object instances that were created.

Just do something like:

```
class BaseballCardBox {
private:
    static int maxCardCount; // replace to this
.
.
.
};

int BaseballCardBox::maxCardCount; // and this
```

And you'll get output like:

```
Input the maximum # of cards for the Baseball card Box: 3
Max count of cards: 3
Current count is: 0
Spaces left: 3

Max count of cards: 3
Current count is: 1
Spaces left: 2

Max count of cards: 3
Current count is: 2
Spaces left: 1
```

Comment: Wow it was something that small of adding static to int. It worked and so does everything else.